# Dynamic files for phpmailer using dompdf

Tags: phpmailer, php, dompdf

I am generating pdf file using dompdf whose filename keeps changing as I have assigned a variable in dompdf stream output and this filename always remains as unique filename.

I want to attach a file in my mail where I am using phpmailer.

Problem:
Able to attach file properly if I assign a particular file name in phpmailer as static file(with particular name assigned), but not getting successful for dynamic files (using variable as below). Here, `$attach` is my php variable for file name.

Trying out below code:

```
$dompdf->stream($attach);//Code for dompdf

$mail->AddAttachment('C:\Downloads\$attach.pdf');  //code for phpmailer to attach file
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What i did is like this...........

```
       I got all my html code in the following variable called `$html`.Then i followed below procedure.
$dompdf->load_html($html);    
$dompdf->render();
$pdf = $dompdf->output();
$file_location will have dynamic file name.
file_put_contents($file_location,$pdf);
```

Now use this $file_location variable for attaching the file name to php mailer. This you need to write in the same php file where you are generating pdf.

Comment: Hi Venkat, Still no luck!! Tried below.. FOR DOMPDF:$dompdf = new DOMPDF(); 
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$pdf = $dompdf->output();
file_put_contents($file_location,$pdf); AND BELOW CODE FOR PHPMAILER:$mail->AddAttachment ($file_location);

Comment: what you are getting in $file_location

Comment: Hi Venkat, Tried this $pdf = $dompdf->output();
file_put_contents($file_location,$pdf);

$mail->AddStringAttachment($pdf, attach.pdf); and working fine now :). Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Hi venkat, Just wanted to know.. Are u aware about this error. 'Unable to stream pdf: headers already sent' getting this in dompdf

Comment: @sidd typically indicates that the PDF was rendered and dompdf is attempting to send it to the browser. The message means something else in the code has already sent content and is preventing dompdf from setting the content-type headers.

Comment: I got the solution for this!! $dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
//$dompdf->stream($PNR);
$pdf = $dompdf->output();
file_put_contents($file_location,$pdf); @brian and venkat, thanks for your valuable response